# stop function on mouseleave jquery

Tags: jquery, function, mouseevent, mouseover

I'm trying to use mouseenter and mouseleave to start and stop a color animation function, however it doesn't stop on mouseleave...please help me figure out:

A: If mouseenter/leave is the correct event to call (or should I be using mouseover or hover?)

B: The correct structure for using .stop to end a function

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#logo").bind('mouseenter', function() {
            pixelColors() });

        $("#logo").bind('mouseleave', function() {
            pixelColors().stop(true, true); });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: do you mean that you can't bind the mouse leave event or you mean that the stop function is not working ?

Comment: Let's see your pixelColors() function.

Comment: .stop() is supposed to be called on an element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interstellar_Coder has it right; you need to call stop on a jquery object; try replacing pixelColors in your callback function with jQuery(this), i.e. jQuery(this).stop(true, true);

Comment: Okay great! I had two conflicts, one being InterStellar's solution to use .stop() on the element AND thanks to their clue to see the pixelColors script, i realized I still had window setTimeout there, which conflicted with the mouseover/leave events. Thanks y'all! I learned a lot :)

Comment: (Should this be a new question?) Now that I've got the mouseenter/leave working, I need to keep the script running as long as the mouse is over #logo. As of now it only changes the color once when we use mouseenter.